# Importing images in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Dear All, I have another issue. I have in the SQL table Employees. This table has lot of details but I was missing images or photos.

So i managed to take all pictures for all employees but I have the pictures in the folder. Each picture is named like an Employee_id which matches the record in the table. How do I import images into SQL Employee table to match the name of the picture to Employee_id.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cursor and a bit of dynamic SQL should do the trick.

```
declare EmployeeCursor cursor fast_forward for
    select Employee_id
        from Employee

declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
declare @Employee_id int

open EmployeeCursor      

while (1=1) begin
    fetch next from EmployeeCursor into @Employee_id

    if @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 break

    set @sql = N'UPDATE Employee
                     SET ImageColumn = 
                         (SELECT * FROM 
                              OPENROWSET(BULK N''c:\images\' + cast(@Employee_id as nvarchar(10)) + N'.jpg'', SINGLE_BLOB) AS img)
                              WHERE Employee_id = ' + cast(@Employee_id as nvarchar(10))

    exec(@sql)   
end /* while */

close EmployeeCursor
deallocate EmployeeCursor
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting but how to use cursor...sorry for asking :-(

Comment: @Tony: I've written everything you need for the cursor in the answer.

Comment: Hi Joe, I get back this error and it didn't import any pictures. Does the Employee_id total has to match exacly the total number of pictures or........                                                          Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot bulk load. The file "c:\images\25662.jpg" does not exist.

Comment: I have an id = 025662 not 25662. I am just testing 8 records out of 400 Employees in the table

Comment: OK, my code was just an example. You'll have to modify it to fit your situation. Instead of declaring `@Employee_id` as an INT, declare it to match your datatype.

Comment: A ok, I have the id field as nvarchar and I declared is as int above...ok let me sort it out...

Comment: Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load. The file "c:\images\025662.jpg" does not exist.

Comment: @Tony: Again, I think you may be taking my example too literally. Are your images stored in `c:\images` or another location? You need to substitute the correct file path. Also, if necessary, adjust the `.jpg` extension to match your real files as well.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I managed to do it however I needed to have matching records on both sides...then it worked....

Comment: @Tony: Yes, since in your question you said you had pictures for *all* employees, I assumed there would be a match on both sides.

Comment: ok I got this figured out, now I have second issue, On the backend I am using MS Access and I can not see the image on the form, it is long binary data....hm... is this for another post?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`OPENROWSET BULK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) to open an external file as a value for an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

Here's an example:

```
UPDATE Employees SET Picture=(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\temp\1234.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) as Picture) WHERE Employee_id=1234
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it thru stored procedure? So I can use it from the application.

Comment: @Tony, you should be able to pass the employee id and filename as parameters to a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks Mark, now big question. How?

Comment: A Mark, thanks, I checked a bit more your code above and I see what you meant, let me try to do that as well...

Comment: Mark, I created the sp for above but what should I put in the 'c:\temp\1234.jpg' as image name....                          I declared the Employee_id=@EmployeeID